# Question on static classes - general use (examples)

Tags: c#, c++, static

Learning static classes, I read some examples and would like to ask whether my opinion is correct:
Menus - MY opinion: is it because I only need one menu and instances of menu are not making sense?
Constant information - MY opinion: I could have simply const variables, right?
Helper methods - MY opinion:  it is because they do not belong to any object and are more "generic"?
Thanks

Comment: Well it is not, I would like to hear whether my assumption are correct or not

Comment: in summary, static classes can act as a container to utility methods (way of code organization) or they can be used as a singleton (but I would prefer other implementations). However, all these (and more) are covered in the thread sighted!

Comment: And why the question tagged 'c++'?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any reading/research before you posted here?

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Static classes and class members are
>   used to create data and functions that
>   can be accessed without creating an
>   instance of the class.
>
> Use a static class as a unit of
>   organization for methods not
>   associated with particular objects.
>   Also, a static class can make your
>   implementation simpler and faster
>   because you do not have to create an
>   object in order to call its methods.
>   It is useful to organize the methods
>   inside the class in a meaningful way,
>   such as the methods of the Math class
>   in the System namespace.

And from [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> **A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of
>   methods that just operate on input
>   parameters and do not have to get or
>   set any internal instance fields.**
>   For example, in the .NET Framework
>   Class Library, the static System.Math
>   class contains methods that perform
>   mathematical operations, without any
>   requirement to store or retrieve data
>   that is unique to a particular
>   instance of the Math class. That is,
>   you apply the members of the class by
>   specifying the class name and the
>   method name, as shown in the following
>   example.

Comment: Yep I did. I would just like to know whether I understood well. The examples I gave were taken from soem article and I add my explanation based on my understanding.

Comment: Well, I think the static class with static fields can store data..

Comment: I don't think you understood the intent of Tommcat's question. He was asking for a narrative when to use static classes and why should one prefer static classes over other possible solutions.